# How to enable and disable tab-pane inputs elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, tabpanel

I have created a tab-pane using bootstrap as shown in my code snippet below (2 tabs) and both contain multiple ul->li->input check boxes. I am trying to do as if Tab_01(tab_urban) is active then allow to select check boxes from Tab_01 not from Tab_02(tab_rural)-> disable check boxes vice versa. Unable to identify where I am doing mistake.

[image: a busy cat]

```
##JS
var el_u = document.getElementById('urban');
var chk_r = document.getElementsByClassName('myCheck_u');

var el_r = document.getElementById('rural');
var chk_u = document.getElementsByClassName('myCheck_r');

if ((hasClass(el_u, 'active')) == true && (hasClass(el_r, 'active')) !== true) {
    console.log('urban selected');
    for (var k = 0; k < chk_r.length; k++) {
        chk_r[k].disabled = false;
    }
    for (var k = 0; k < chk_u.length; k++) {
        chk_u[k].disabled = true;
    }
} else if ((hasClass(el_r, 'active')) == true && (hasClass(el_u, 'active')) !== true) {
    console.log('rural selected');
    for (var k = 0; k < chk_u.length; k++) {
        chk_r[k].disabled = true;
    }
    for (var k = 0; k < chk_r.length; k++) {
        chk_u[k].disabled = false;
    }
}
/*******************************************/
##HTML
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li id="urban" class="active"><a href="#tab_urban" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li id="rural" class=""><a href="#tab_rural" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_urban">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input class="myCheck_u" type="checkbox" name="Wave_fiters[]" value="1"> Wave-1 </li>
            <li>
                <input class="myCheck_u" type="checkbox" name="Wave_fiters[]" value="2"> Wave-2 </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_rural">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <input class="myCheck_r" type="checkbox" name="HS1_fiters[]" value="1"> Entertainment Sites </li>
            <li>
                <input class="myCheck_r" type="checkbox" name="HS1_fiters[]" value="2"> News </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tabs are changing it's state.

- Initially in Tab_01 all inputs all can be checked and in Tab_02 are
  disabled  When I am change tab(Tab_01 to Tab_02) not enabling the
  input check boxes of Tab_02 and disabling Tab_01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works as you've requested, but I started again with the code as I felt it could be simplified a little using jquery.

The jquery is fully commented, but let me know if you don't understand something or were hoping for something else.

I commented out the `display: none;` CSS rule so you could see the other checkboxes were disabled.

Hope it helps

---

## Demo

```js
// Add click event to tab links
$("a[data-toggle='tab']").click(function() {

  // Remove active classes from tab link and panels
  $("a[data-toggle='tab'].active").removeClass("active");
  $("div.tab-pane.active").removeClass("active");

  // Add active class to the tab link and panel
  $(this).addClass("active");
  $("div.tab-pane" + $(this).attr("href")).addClass("active");

  // Disable all inputs
  $("div.tab-pane input").attr("disabled", "disabled");

  // Enable inputs on the active tab
  $("div.tab-pane.active input").removeAttr("disabled");

});


// Click the link to run function on load
$("#urban > a").click();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li id="urban" class="active"><a href="#tab_urban" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">Urban Tab 1</a></li>
  <li id="rural" class=""><a href="#tab_rural" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">Rural Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab_urban">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input class="myCheck_u" type="checkbox" name="Wave_fiters[]" value="1"> Wave-1 </li>
      <li>
        <input class="myCheck_u" type="checkbox" name="Wave_fiters[]" value="2"> Wave-2 </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab_rural">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input class="myCheck_r" type="checkbox" name="HS1_fiters[]" value="1"> Entertainment Sites </li>
      <li>
        <input class="myCheck_r" type="checkbox" name="HS1_fiters[]" value="2"> News </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is not working when I am adding Bootstrap v3.3.7!

Comment: Updated to include Bootstrap v3.3.7... it's still working. There must be some over code causing your issue...

Comment: Not its working fine, cause an issue with some adminlte 2 files